# Why is an electric dipole neutral overall and still has energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, dipole

We are taught that only charged particles have an electric field in their vicinity and a neutral object does not. But a dipole is neutral overall and still produces an electric field. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall a neutral dielectric can be seen as having a neutral charge distribution, but when you only have 2 opposite point charges, it does not work.

The electric field produced by a dipole is
[image: Electric field of a dipole]

Demonstration for the potential can be found here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dipole.html

We can check that this field satisfies what neutral objects do by using the following maxwell equation $\int\int \vec{E}\cdot\vec{\sigma} =Q/\epsilon$
for neutral objects we have Q = 0
computing this integral for using our dipole electric field also yields 0

Please ask if i can clarify any points

Comment: Thank You. As a beginner in physics, just wanted to know that what is the key distinction between a dipole and a nuetral object (which does not cause an electric field) ? Also,if two charged particles like an electron or proton fuse together, does their electric field magically vanish (exactly cancel each other) or form a point dipole ?

Comment: I think the collision between 2 elementary particles of opposit charges is not of the domain of maxwell's equations (I ont know what would happen), but if we look at the field equation for the dipole we see that as the charges get closer to one another the field diminishes until 0.

Comment: Uhmm.. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Between a negative and positive charged particle you have an electric field, an a dipole has both. Most el. fields start at one charge and end on another.